# Trello API: Unable to modifiy/delete a checklistitem

Tags: trello

I'm coding a power-up but due to limited API functionality, i'm using the Trello client API inside the power-up.
Everything is working fine up to now but i'm not able to change the checklist item state as "complete".

I haven't found a specific API for that!

So i tried to create a new cheklist item checked and then delete the incomplete cheklist item.

```
function completeCicle(cod_cicle){
  // there is no API to "complete" a checkitem. So i made two steps:
  // 1 - copy the checkitem content to a new checkitem
  // 2 - delete the uncomplete checkitem
  var CI = getCheckItemCicle(cod_cicle); // get the in-memory unchecked checkitem object
  Trello.post("/checklists/"+CI.idChecklist+"/checkItems",{name:CI.name, pos:String(CI.pos+1), checked:"true"}); // this works
  Trello.delete("/checklists/"+CI.idChecklist+"/checkItems/"+CI.id,{idCheckItem:CI.id}, t_error); // this did not works
}
```

But ... the delete seems to have not any effect and no errors are raised.
Any idea?

Comment: How do you get the Trello client inside the power-up?

Answer (score 1):

The API route to change the state of a checkitem is under the cards route.

For full documentation you can see the Trello developers website here: https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/card#put-1-cards-card-id-or-shortlink-checklist-idchecklist-checkitem-idcheckitem-state

However, the short version is that you can do

`PUT /1/cards/[card id or shortlink]/checklist/[idChecklist]/checkItem/[idCheckItem]/state`

Where the argument to that endpoint is `value=` one of `complete, false, incomplete, true`.

So for example to mark a checkitem as done you would do:

`PUT /1/cards/[card id or shortlink]/checklist/[idChecklist]/checkItem/[idCheckItem]/state?value=complete`